# Help for a regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am new to RegeX and need something that does the following:
input: some word that starts with everything, follows by something fixed like "_CHR" and then immediately with some digit like 123 and then anything else. I want to find those and replace that number with the Character representation of that number...
so for example: input: " Hello Pi_CHR241to How are you"
will be replaced with "Hello Piñto How are you"

Comment: I would suggest to use the regular HTML syntax for this: `&__;`.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like an encoding problem workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Since you only want to replace the `_CHRnnn` bits, it's enough to search for:

```
_CHR(\d+)
```

After the match, backreference number 1 will contain the character code.

With this, you can:

```
string resultString = null;
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"_CHR(\d+)", new MatchEvaluator(ComputeReplacement));

public String ComputeReplacement(Match m) {
    return ToString((char)(Int32.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value)));
}
```

EDIT: Thanks to Alan Moore for his C# expertise and regex improvement ideas!

Comment: thanks, how can I get number 2 for exmple after the match? becasue I should tell it to replace it with the Character code of that number

Comment: for that part I tried this  ((char) (Int32.Parse("$2"))) and worked but the problem is that it does not get the breakpoint at ComputeReplacement at all... I think there is something wrong with the RegEx pattern we are using in here,

Comment: Which breakpoint? Do you mean that `ComputeReplacement` is never called at all?

Comment: yes, ComputeReplacement  is not getting called. which means something is wrong with RegEx I think.

Comment: Hm. I take it that `_CHR` really occurs exactly like this in your text? The regex is case-sensitive. Can you post an actual sample of your text in your question?

Comment: The `"2"` in your code should be `m.Groups[2].Value`.  The same would be true for `"$1"` and `"$3"`, but I don't see why you need them.  You're only replacing the `_CHRnnn` tokens, so that's all you need to match.  Also, you seem to be assuming there will be only one token per string.  If there are two or more, your code will only replace the last one.

Comment: @Alan Moore: Thanks! I hope that the new version is now correct.

Comment: (I of course meant `"$2"` above, not `"2"`.)  Tim: That won't compile because you're trying to cast an Int32 to a String.  The correct way to do that would be to call `ToString()` on the Int32.  But that will give you back a String representation of the Int32, which is what you started with.  You need to cast the Int32 to a Char and call ToString() on *that*, like @Patrick did (but without the `HexNumber` specifier).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, Tim, are you aware that you can test C# code on http://ideone.com ?

Comment: @Alan Moore: No, I wasn't. That is a great link. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, theoretically your string could start or end with one of your 'encoding' string, so I don't know that you want to worry about what is before or after it, but just find occurrences of any instance of that pattern.

Assuming you are looking for any unicode character, you could look either for up to 4 hexadecimal digits, or up to 5 decimal digits. So your RegEx could look something like the following:

**HEX:** `_CHR[0-9A-F]{1,4}`
**DEC:** `_CHR[0-9]{1,5}`

If you want to match either format, try something like the following:

`_CHR([0-9A-F]{1,4}|[0-9]{1,5})`

I don't think you can do the replacement you want with the RegEx directly. RegEx generally just does a straight replacement, where you are looking for a functional replacement. But whatever language you are coding in it should be easy enough to get a collection of the matches and loop through it, parsing them and replacing as needed.

**EDIT:**
Regarding your matching question, I can't give specifics without knowing your language. But in pseudo-code, you'd do something along the lines of the following:

```
Dim pMatches = RegEx.Matches(myInput, myPattern)  
Const pfx As String  = "_CHAR", ccode As String  
For Each m As Match in pMatches  
    ccode = m.Value.Replace(pfx, "")
    myInput.Replace(m.Value, GetUniChar(ccode))  
Next
```

That is roughly VB.NET syntax, but you'd need to translate it as appropriate to whatever language you're using. If you need explanation of any of it, comment back.

Comment: yes, exactly, looking for coe of  unicode characters and replacing them with their real characters... I used your DEC regEx and worked well ... now what is next? Ok I say regEx.IsMatch (reg)... then it stops somewhere that finds the match ... so now how can I know what was the index of that place that matched? how many more characters I should read, etc

Comment: Oh, actually Tim Pietzcker has better code for processing the matches if you can get it working. Forgot about the RegEx.Replace function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with that method is that if the text following the symbol is also a number, the regex pattern could easily mistake it for the rest of the symbol. You'd be much better off to use the html standard `&#F1;` instead. If you must use the method in the example, you'd have to use a fixed number of digits.

```
string resultString = null;
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"&#([0-9A-Fa-f]+);", new MatchEvaluator(ComputeReplacement));
//alternateive: @"_CHR(\d{3})" - fixed number of digits
//or: @"_CHR(\d+)" - ABSOLUTELY SURE a number will never follow a special character

public string ComputeReplacement(Match m) {
    return ((char)(int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value, NumberStyles.HexNumber))).ToString();
}
```